# How to find a point on 2-d weighted map, which will have equidistant (as close as possible) paths to multiple endpoints?

Tags: path-finding

So let's say I got a matrix with two types of cells: 0 and 1. 1 is not passable.

I want to find a point, from which I can run paths (say, A*) to a bunch of destinations (don't expect it to be more than 4). And I want the length of these paths to be such that l1/l2/l3/l4 = 1 or as close to 1 as possible.

For two destinations is simple: run a path between them and take the midpoint. For more destinations, I imagine I can run paths between each pair, then they will create a sort of polygon, and I could grab the centroid (or average of all path point coordinates)? Or would it be better to take all midpoints of paths between each pair and then use them as vertices in a polygon which will contain my desired point?

Comment: Could you post a diagram of what you are trying to do? I'm not clear on what your objective is. you want all of your paths to be 1, if you want that everything would need to be next to each other would it not?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to find the point with best access to multiple endpoints. For other readers, this is like trying to found an ideal settlement to trade with nearby cities; you want them to be as accessible as possible. It appears to be a variant of the [Weber Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_problem) applied to pathfinding.

The best solution, as you can no longer rely on exploiting geometry (imagine a mountain path or two blocking the way), is going to be an iterative approach. I don't imagine it will be easy to find an optimal solution because you'll need to check every square; you can't guess by pathing between endpoints anymore. In nearly any large problem space, you will need to path from each possible centroid to all endpoints. A suboptimal solution will be fairly fast. I recommend these steps:

1. **try to estimate the centroid** using geometry, forming a search area
2. **Use a modified A* algorithm** from each point `S` in the search area to all your target points T to generate a perfect path from `S` to each `T`.
3. **Add the length of each path** `S -> T` together to get `Cost` (probably stored in a matrix for all sample points)
4. **Select the lowest `Cost`** from all your samples in the matrix (or the entire population if you didn't cull the search space).

The algorithm above can also work without estimating a centroid and limiting solutions. If you choose to search the entire space, the search will be much longer, but you can find a perfect solution even in a labyrinth. If you estimate the centroid and start the search near it, you'll find good answers faster.

I mentioned earlier that you should use a modified A* algorithm... Rather than repeating a generic A* search `S->Tn` for every T, code A* so that it seeks multiple target locations, storing the paths to each one and stopping when it has found them all.

If you *really* want a perfect solution to the problem, you'll be waiting a long time, so I recommend that you use any exploit you can to reduce wasteful calculations. Even go so far as to store found paths in a lookup table for each `T`, and see if a point already exists along any of those paths.

To put it simply, finding the point is easy. Finding it fast-enough might take lots of clever heuristics (cost-saving measures) and stored data.